# How to root Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7.0?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7

I have been trying to  root my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7.0 (SM-T217S; Firmware version T217SVPUBNH4).

Since the September update I can't re-root my tablet, I have tried apps like Vroot(app), towelroot, and pretty much all the rooting apps available for Android.

I also tried programs like Kingo Root, one click root, vroot for PC, and many alike. I haven't tried flashing the TWRP or ClockworkMod Recovery. I tried a while back with TWRP but it failed.

How do I root my device?
.

Answer (score 1):

## Here's a way to do it using TWRP

1. Put the superuser.zip file in your tablet and Boot into Download Mode (Hold Vol Down +Power to turn on the Device).
2. Unzip the TWRP Recovery Image after downloading it below.
3. Connect your tablet to your PC, unzip and run Odin, click the PDA button and select the TWRP md5 file you just unzipped.
4. Begin holding the Volume Up button on your Tablet and hit the start button in Odin (this will ensure you reboot into the new recovery)

Once in TWRP if you select the reboot option under advanced you should be prompted to root your device if it's not already rooted. If that doesn't happen for some reason you can use adb to sideload the SuperSU zip I've attached, or put it on an sd card and find the flash zip from sdcard option in TWRP to flash it.

### Download files

1. [Odin307.zip](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2563964&d=1391756296)
2. [SuperSU-v1.93.zip](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2563965&d=1391756444)
3. [TWRP-2.6.3.0-recovery.tar.zip](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2566158&d=1391842969)

Answer (score 0):

it's simple, flash TWRP using Odin, boot into recovery and TWRP will prompt you to root.

1.Boot into Download Mode (Hold Vol Down +Power to turn on the Device)Unzip the TWRP Recovery Image after downloading it below.

2.Connect your tablet to your PC, unzip and run Odin, click the PDA button and select the TWRP md5 file you just unzipped.

3.Begin holding the Volume Up button on your Tablet and hit the start button in Odin (this will ensure you reboot into the new recovery)

4.Once in TWRP if you select the reboot option under advanced you should be prompted to root your device if it's not already rooted. If that doesn't happen for some reason you can use adb to sideload the SuperSU zip I've attached, or put it on an sd card and find the flash zip from sdcard option in TWRP to flash it.

[odin.zip](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2563964&d=1391756296)

[SuperSu.zip](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=2563965&d=1391756444)

hope I helped..

Comment: If you put a space between X. and your content, then you would see a numbered line. E.g. `1. Begin` contrary to `1.Begin`. That would help us in readability and help you to present it in pure numbered list, even if you mistake in the number system would correct it. :)